# Сложить дубликаты

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

Имеются строки-дубликаты. 
Например,

```
A 1
B 2
A 3
C 8
B 4
```

Нужно сложить значения дублирующихся. Т.е

```
A 4 
B 6 
C 8
```

Comment: Сгруппируйте по первому столбцу, по второму посчитайте сумму - все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша таблица:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list("ABACB"), (1, 2, 3, 8, 4)]).T
df
```

> ```
>       0   1
> 0     A   1
> 1     B   2
> 2     A   3
> 3     C   8
> 4     B   4
> ```

Команда:

```
df.groupby(0).sum()
```

> ```
>       1
> 0     
> A     4
> B     6
> C     8
> ```

или — когда вы хотите получить таблицу, а не серию — добавите еще `.reset_index()`:

```
df.groupby(0).sum().reset_index()
```

> ```
>       0   1
> 0     A   4
> 1     B   6
> 2     C   8
> ```

Вместо `0` («имя» моего столбца) используйте имя вашего столбца, например

`df.groupby("column_1").sum()`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Rz79ib4j
В таком случае не получается сохранить все по дням, после суммы и groupby получается смешение дней. @MarianD

Comment: `df.groupby(["День", "Продукт"]).sum()`